# Clarity on AWS SNS message attributes documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am not able to understand the line which AWS SNS doc says [Message attributes are optional and separate from, but sent along with, the message body. This information can be used by the receiver of the message to help decide how to handle the message without having to first process the message body](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-attributes.html)

So, Does this mean that when i publish a message along with message attributes via SNS, will it also be sent to the endpoint who has subscribed to SNS (specifically HTTP subscriber)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried sending message attributes via SNS to HTTP subscriber and I was able to receive them as headers. So, yes you can receive the message attributes via http subscriber.

Note : I have tried this in mule anypoint studio.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the code that allowed you to do this? I'm having trouble accessing SNS message attributes via an HTTP endpoint. For more information on my particular issue, please see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/55930596/6037139 if you have some time.